# Riemann–Stieltjes integral with $\alpha(x) = \beta(x)$ for any $x \in [a,b]$ which $f$ is not continuous at $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Question: Let $f,\alpha,\beta$ be bounded on $[a,b]$ so that $\alpha(x) = \beta(x)$ for any $x \in [a,b]$ which $f$ is not continuous at $x$. If $f$ is continuous except for finitely many points in $[a,b]$ then $\int_a^bf \, d \alpha$ exists if and only if $\int_a^b f\, d \beta$ exists.

My attempt: The statement is false. Set $a = -1,b = 1$ and
define
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x \in [-1, 0) \\1 & x \in [0,1]
\end{cases}$$
$$
\alpha(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x \in [-1,0]\\ 1 & x \in (0,1]
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\beta(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \in [-1, -\frac{1}{2}]\\ 0 & x \in [-\frac{1}{2}, 1]
\end{cases}
$$
So, $f$ is discontinuous only at $x=0$, $\alpha$ is discontinuous only at $x =0$, $\beta$ is discontinuous at $x = -\frac{1}{2}$. At $x =0$ we have $\alpha(0) = 0 = \beta(0)$.

Let $\Gamma = \{x_i\}_{i=0}^m$ be any partition of $[-1,1]$ and any arbitrary intermediate points $\{\xi_i\}_{i=1}^m$ so that $x_{i-1} \leq \xi_i \leq x_i$ we define
$$R_{\Gamma, \alpha} := \sum_{i=1}^m f(\xi_i)[\alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i-1})], \quad R_{\Gamma, \beta} := \sum_{i=1}^m f(\xi_i)[\beta(x_i) - \beta(x_{i-1})]$$ and the Riemann–Stieltjes integral as
$$I_\alpha = \lim_{|\Gamma| \to 0}R_{\Gamma, \alpha}, \quad I_\beta = \lim_{|\Gamma| \to 0}R_{\Gamma, \beta}$$ whenever the limit exists.
Given a partition $\Gamma = \{x_i\}_{i=0}^m$ of $[-1,1]$ then $$-1 = x_0 <x_1 < \dots < x_k < x_{k+1} < \dots < x_m = 1$$ where $k$ is the smallest integer so that $x_k \leq - \frac{1}{2}$ then
\begin{align*}
R_{\Gamma, \beta} &= \sum_{i=1}^m f(\xi)[\beta(x_i) - \beta(x_{i-1})]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k f(\xi_i)[\beta(x_i) - \beta(x_{i-1})] + \sum_{i=k+1}^m f(\xi_i)[\beta(x_i) - \beta(x_{i-1})]\\
&= 0
\end{align*}
where for the first sum, the intermediate points $f(\xi_i) =0$ whereas for the second sum the difference $\beta(x_i) - \beta(x_{i-1}) =0$. Thus, the Riemann-Stieltjes integral
$$\int_{-1}^1 f \, d\beta = 0$$
On the other hand, if $\Gamma = \{x_i\}_{i=0}^m$ is partition of $[a,b]$ with
$$-1 = x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_{k-1} < x_k < x_{k+1} < \dots < x_k$$ so that $x_{k-1} < 0 < x_k$, then we have $R_{\Gamma, \alpha} = f(\xi_k)$. Because $R_{\Gamma, \alpha} \in \{0,1\}$ so the limit cannot exists. Therefore, $\int_{-1}^1 f \, d \alpha$ does not exist.

Do let me know if there any gaps in my proof.